# Probability when parameter varies according to a distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm working on the following problem:

"The probability that an insured individual will give rise to no claims next year is $e^{-\theta}$, where $\theta$ varies by individuals according to the density function $f_\Theta(\theta) = 25\theta e^{-5\theta}$. What is the probability that a randomly selected individual will give rise to no claims next year?"

My intuition was essentially to multiply the probability of a certain $\theta$ by the probability of no claims for that $\theta$, and I approached that by finding $\int_0^\infty25\theta e^{-5\theta}e^{-(25\theta e^{-5\theta})}$, which came out as $\approx 0.335824$. Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite.

Suppose $\theta$ is given then the probability of no claim is is $\exp(-\theta).$

\begin{align}
Pr(\text{no claim}) &= \int_0^\infty Pr(\text{no claim}|\theta)f_\Theta(\theta) \, d\theta\\
&= \int_0^\infty \exp(-\theta) f_\Theta(\theta) \, d\theta
\end{align}